# Excel document lost all data

Tags: excel, office365

I was working on an Excel document and I used the key combination **Alt+h+w** to wrap a text paragraph, but for my surprise that makes disappear all my **sheets and cells**, below an actual view:

[Excel doc actual state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkr9Z.png)

I have never seen an error like this in Excell before just after doing the keyboard combination **Alt+h+w** the document is not corrupted and has his actual size of 379kb, meaning that still has his data **somewhere**.

I did open all other excel documents and Excel is working fine, I did open a back up of this file from two months ago and the file size is **350kb** meaning that size-wise is fine with only 20kb increase in two months but size are similar so is not about losing data.

I will appreciate all your help.

Comment: Have you checked if Alt+h+w has been defined somewhere for a specific task?

Comment: Hi @Solar Mike 2, No idea what do you mean by that to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the view, menu select unhide which will bring back all the information to the foreground